# How to programatically set the selected state for a segment in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have four segments in my UISegmentedControl. I am trying to programmatically set the selected state of the third and fourth segments **at the same time** if the user has selected the first segment.

Example: In a given segmented control, if the user selected segment A, then C, D should be selected.

I looked into Apple's methods but found none that match my requirement. I am looking for a method that would look like-

Any help on this is much appreciated.

---

-(void) setSelected: (BOOL) selected forSegmentAtIndex: (NSUInteger) segment

**Parameters**

*enabled*

YES to select the specified segment or NO to unselect the segment. By default, segments are unselected.

*segment*

An index number identifying a segment in the control. It must be a number between 0 and the number of segments (numberOfSegments) minus 1; values exceeding this upper range are pinned to it.

---

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4.0**

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = index
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `setSelectedSegmentIndex` like so -

```
[mySegmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:index]
```

Comment: hi- I tried this at first but the setSelectedSegmentIndex: message only selects one segment at a time. I would like to select c,d at once if user selects segment a.

Comment: @Revanth - Your choice of the control is not suited for your requirements. As suggested, you should look at building your own control to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

This code is for swift 2.0

```
// Declare outlet for our segmented control
@IBOutlet weak var segmentcontroll: UISegmentedControl!

// Declare our IBAction for the segmented control
@IBAction func segmentneeded(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Here we test for the presently selected segment
    switch segmentcontroll.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.purpleColor()
        segmentcontroll.selectedSegmentIndex=UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    case 1:
        self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.yellowColor()
        segmentcontroll.selectedSegmentIndex=UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    default:
        self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.grayColor()
        segmentcontroll.selectedSegmentIndex=UISegmentedControlNoSegment
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `UISegmentedControl` works like a set of radio buttons. That is, only one segment can be selected at a time.  To get the functionality that you want, you will need to make a custom control that looks like a `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: Thank you. I can group some buttons together to make it look like a UISegmenetedControl and add the custom functionality I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

First, create an outlet from the segmented control you've added from the UI

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
```

Using the code below programmatically change the selected segment

```
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1 // index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `selectedSegmentIndex` property as there is int he documentation

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/selectedSegmentIndex

So simply:

```
[segmentControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:2];
```

Consider that you can set just **1 index** and that if you want **unselect all** you have to set **the index -1**.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically this can not be done in SegmentControl but you can do this way:
You can create one imageView put four button on that which size are equal like segments and make them transparent when on one button is pressed change the image of imageView which look like Segment  C, D are pressed this way you can do other task.